# How to createan empty list that is associated with the specified comparator (java)?

Tags: java

My question is with the MySortedLinkedList constructor...I know head=null; would be an empty list, but I don't know how to include the comparator.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to assign it to a field:

```
public class MySortedLinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private MyListNode<T> head;
    private final Comparator<T> comparator;

    public MySortedLinkedList(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        head = null;
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }
}
```

You can't do it without introducing an extra field - it's part of what differentiates one instance from another.

Answer (score 0):

Err, add a `Comparator<T> comparator` field to your class, and initialize it from the constructor:

```
private Comparator<T> comparator;

public MySortedLinkedList(Comparator<T> comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
}
```

Also, you made your MyListNode generic, but use the raw type (`MyListNode`) instead of the parameterized one (`MyListNode<T>`).